# Javascript Canvas Sizes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas on a HTML page:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Attributes `width` and `height` stretch the canvas into a certain field, but do not resize it. So

```
var canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvasElement.width = 400;
canvasElement.height = 400;
```

doesn't work.

How can I resize the canvas (make it something not equal to 160*320)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, this way.

```
var canvasElement = document.getElementById('yourCanvasElement');
canvasElement.width = 500;
canvasElement.height = 400;
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and OPs code? (not counting the element id and the pixel sizes)